# Can I use a constructor in Laravel's Form Request class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to use a constructor inside my `CreateLeadRequest` class, but it seems to be failing.

```
class CreateLeadRequest extends FormRequest
{
    private $dealer;
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->dealer = Dealer::findOrFail($this->dealer_id);
    }
}
```

`$this->dealer_id` is coming in as null. I can use it inside `prepareForValidation` and other functions just fine, so why is it coming in as null inside the constructor?

Comment: the FormRequest class doesn't get filled with values until after it is initialized (when resolved from the IoC container) [ `Request@createFrom`]

Comment: correction ... "... filled with values until after it is instantiated"

Comment: So is it possible to set a property and re-use it in there without using a constructor?

Comment: Override the `initialize` function. Just make sure to call the `parent::initialize` first with all of the arguments passed in. Then you should be able to load the Dealer object after

Comment: is there a particular reason this FormRequest needs a Dealer instance?

Comment: @lagbox I can probably get away with it. I ended up getting the dealer object inside my `withValidator` function and just passing it as an argument inside my other functions that do various validations. Previously I was getting the dealer object separately inside each validation function.